# How to preserve checked checkbox after closing the modal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I have a modal that looks like this:
[image]

After few checkboxes has been checked and after clicking on `Add Users to New Group` modal closes and I'm catching values of checked checkboxes. But now I need those checkboxes that were checked before closing modal to stay checked after opening modal again, so that user can see which one of checkboxes he checked, if that is even possible to do. Here is what I tried:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#addNewMembers').click(function(){//click on Add Users to New Group button
     var selected = $('#ovdjeSuSelektovani').val();//im putting value of all checked checkboxes inside hidden input, so this is how i'm retrieving those values
     console.log(selected);
     if(selected!='') {
        var arrayOfSelected = selected.split(",");
        for(var i=0;i<arrayOfSelected.length;i++){
            $('checkbox value=['+arrayOfSelected[i]+']').prop('checked',true);//did not recognize the jQuery selector
        }
        var numberOfSelected=arrayOfSelected.length;
        $('#numberOfMembers').text(numberOfSelected)
    }else{//neko upozorenje    
    }    
});
```

Did not work.
Attempt No.2:

```
$("#modal-6 input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
       this.prop('checked',true);
});
```

Did nothing after reopening the modal. If anyone has any advice, I would be glad to try it.

Comment: use localstorage to save the state and on open use that saved state to correct the state of checkboxes

Comment: in your attempt #2 why are you using `:checked`?

Comment: @Idan b Because when button is clicked all checked checkboxes should preserve their states. Thought with `.prop` it would work.

Comment: the `:checked` in the selector make you select only the checked checkboxes and they are all unchecked when you open your modal arent they?

Comment: Check the code for the modal opening... Does it get its data from an ajax call ? If so, this is the code you should show... And local storage would be good.

Comment: When ever make changes in check box, store the values in a cached object (or a global variable/local storage etc). Then when ever opens the popup write a code to select those check boxes from that cache

Comment: @Hari... Exact, but on each modal open, data has to be retreived from local storage too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no html tag `checkbox`, so this will not work

```
$('checkbox value=['+arrayOfSelected[i]+']').prop('checked',true);
```

try this instead

```
$('input[type=checkbox][value='+arrayOfSelected[i]+']').prop('checked',true);
```

Then it will pick the checkboxes and leave them selected until you explicitly uncheck them.

Comment: Console says `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[type=checkbox] value=[10207252567926988]`

Comment: Corrected it. Try it now

Comment: I've found some other way of doing it yesterday, but tried your's answer now and it worked as well.

Answer (score 0):

When you close the modal store unique identifiers for each checked checkbox in the session storage. The unique identifier can be the Facebook ID for example.

You can read more about Session Storage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). The two methods that you're going to find really helpful are:

`sessionStorage.setItem`

and

`sessionStorage.getItem`

I recommend using the Session Storage instead of the local storage because session storage is not persistent and you probably don't need to keep the checked checkboxes after the browser window has been closed.

In case you want to use the local storage or want to learn more about it you can check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Answer (score 0):

store the id's of ONLY the selected checkboxes in $('#ovdjeSuSelektovani').val() (e.g. "id1,id3,id4"), not the states:

```
$('#modal-6 input[type='checkbox']').is('checked').each(function() {
  $('#ovdjeSuSelektovani').val($('#ovdjeSuSelektovani').val() + $(this).attr('id') + ',');
});

$('#ovdjeSuSelektovani').val($('#ovdjeSuSelektovani').val().replace(/,$/g,'')); //removes training comma
```

when the popup then reloads, try this:

```
$('#ovdjeSuSelektovani').val().split(',').each(function(id) {
  $('#' + id).prop('checked', true);
}
```